# Why the simulation I made in Blender has a different behavior by changing only the size of element?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I premise that is the first time I use Blender.

I would like to simulate a Cubipod installation by a construction crane, for my Master Thesis project in Coastal Engineering . First of all, I should simulate the fall of this element by hand (Cubipod is a rock armour unit deployed to defend ports and shores from wave attack) , using the size of Laboratory rock armour unit (= 3,5 cm). The problem is that with this dimension I've an unstable simulation, unlike when using a bigger size of the element (scaled 50:1). The only parameters I've to implement are in the rigid body, using Mesh as shape collisions. Apart from the mass of the element (which varies with size), the other features are the same for both the Lab size and the model 50:1.

The Cubipod file I imported is Collada (.dae); I've also the .stl version, but has a worse behavior.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: In the Scene Settings under Rigid Body World you can change the number of Steps per second and the Solver Iterations. This will make the simulation more precise at the expense of longer calculation times.

Comment: I've tried to do what you said, but there is still the same problem (the Cubipod pass through the plane mesh when falling). I don't know if could be a problem due to the format file.

Comment: Check the Meshes for non-Manifold faces/edges and fix them, in Edit mode from the Select menu. Also try thickening your plane. If all else fails post the file (or a sub set) here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: There is still the same problem also after fix the meshes; anyway I've just uploaded the file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to edit your question to include the link

Comment: Start with setting the Physics to Convex Hull rather than Mesh and set the Origin to Geometry. That gets the simulation at least stopping the Cubipod from falling beyond the base, but it is not perfect. You can also alter the Grid physics to have a non 0 Sensitivity Margin. I tried to Apply Scale transforms and it went a bit haywire so I guess that is were the root problem lays.

Comment: Previously I had set the Physics to Convex Hull, but with this setting the adjustment of Cubipod after hitting the ground don't represent what happens on the construction site.